# Как убрать смещение при добавлении border

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, css-animation

Как убрать смещение элемента при добавлении border? Так же из за этого смещаются и другие рядом стоящие элементы.

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
a {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 15px 30px;

}

a:hover {
  border: 5px solid;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">First</a>
  <a href="">Second</a>
  <a href="">Third</a>
</nav>
```

Сразу возникла идея сделать через:

```
box-sizing: border-box - не работает, так как нету четких размеров (width, height)
```

Подскажите, как лучше все решить?

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
a {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}

a:hover {
  border-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">First</a>
  <a href="">Second</a>
  <a href="">Third</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: при hover достаточно цвет только поменять, а не заново все настройки границ делать

Comment: @Grundy исправлено!

Answer (score 1):

Надо каждый отступ сделать меньше на ширину рамки.
Например, если ширина рамки `2px`, то надо сделать все внутренние отступы `padding: 15px 30px;` меньше на `2px`.
Вот:

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
a {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 15px 30px;

}

a:hover {
  border: 5px solid;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">First</a>
  <a href="">Second</a>
  <a href="">Third</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно при помощи градиентов

```css
body {
  color: #000;
  padding: 20px;
}

a {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}

a:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#551a8b, #551a8b), linear-gradient(#551a8b, #551a8b), linear-gradient(#551a8b, #551a8b), linear-gradient(#551a8b, #551a8b);
  background-size: 100% 5px, 5px 100%, 100% 5px, 5px 100%;
  background-position: 0 0%, 0% 0, 0 100%, 100% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">First</a>
  <a href="">Second</a>
  <a href="">Third</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью `outline` :

```css
body { padding: 20px; }
a { padding: 15px 30px; font-size: 30px; }

a:hover { outline: 5px solid; }
```

```html
<nav><a href="">First</a><a href="">Second</a><a href="">Third</a></nav>
```

С помощью `box-shadow` :

```css
body { padding: 20px; }
a { padding: 15px 30px; font-size: 30px; }

a:hover { box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px currentColor; }
```

```html
<nav><a href="">First</a><a href="">Second</a><a href="">Third</a></nav>
```